# How to output shape ID in Visio-VBA

Tags: vba, shapes, visio

Here is the code in text form in case the image is not loading:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim NoIO As String
   Dim shp1 As Visio.Shape
   NoIO = ComboBox1.Value

   If NoIO = "7" Then
      MsgBox shp1.ID
      'Call test(shp1)'
      'Target shape id selected'
      'Change shape data of that shape'
   End If
   Unload Me
End Sub
```

Whenever I try to output the ID of a shape, I get the error:

> Object variable or With block variable not set

I cannot change the parameters of the subroutine as I get a procedure declaration mismatch since this code runs after a button click on a user form.

Comment: `Set shp1 = Shapes("shp1")` can you write this before the `NoIO` line?

Comment: Hi Vityata. I get the error: Sub or Function not defined when adding that line

Comment: Where have you added the line?

Comment: Directly before:
    NoIO = ComboBox1.Value

Comment: More specifically, it's the Shapes part that it does not recognise

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialised the shape `shp1`. You have not indicated how you are selecting your shape or why you want to select a shape so I have provided a simple example below.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim NoIO As String
   Dim shp1 As Visio.Shape
   NoIO = ComboBox1.Value

   Set shp1 = Application.ActivePage.Shapes(1) ' Example only!

   If NoIO = "7" Then
      MsgBox shp1.ID
   End If
   Unload Me
End Sub
```